# Повторяющаяся со временем функция в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, activity, android-handler

Мне нужно запустить некий процесс в приложении. Используется второстепенная activity, не основная. Соответственно, будут моменты, когда функцию нужно убивать (при выходе с второстепенной на launcher activity), либо просто останавливать и потом заново запускать (например, триггер-кнопка назад)

Попробовал использовать `val screenHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`

Для остановки процесса было сделано две функции, которые работает при нужном состоянии (пауза или нет). Выглядит это все так:

```
screenHandler.post(object: Runnable{
    override fun run() {
        if(isProcess) {
            onProcessUpdate() // если работает
        } else {
            onProcessPause() // если пауза
        }
        screenHandler.postDelayed(this, 50)
    }
})
```

И, вроде бы, прекрасно работает. Но потом я нажимаю на кнопку назад, текущая activity закрывается и открывается предыдущая. Потом я снова запускаю activity с looper'ом, а этот looper ускоряется, а activity не создается заново, даже при явном вызове finish(), будто оно продолжало выполняться на фоне.

Как мне полноценно реализовать этот перезапуск activity, чтобы looper не ускорялся и работал так же, как и при первом его создании? Может быть, стоит реализовать эту игру со временем каким либо боле подходящим способом?

Comment: `Looper.getMainLooper()` возвращает главный петлитель, а это значит, что всё переданное в `screenHandler` будет выполняться в основном потоке. Так как основной поток не уничтожается с уничтожением второй активности, всё будет продолжать работать, а при очередном вызове второй активности `Runnable` ещё раз запускается, и их становится два (видимый эффект: ускорение). Перед выходом всё-таки стоило бы отозвать `Runnable`: `screenHandler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable)`, но придётся сохранить экземпляр `Runnable` для этого или использовать `screenHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, сейчас у меня вся эта штука хранится внутри `override fun oncreate()`. Я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно этот `object: Runnable{...}` вынести за класс и дать ему имя (внутри мне не дает), например `object runLooper: Runnable{...}`, а внутри `onCreate()` заменить screenHandler.post(...) на `screenHandler.post(runLooper)`, а убирать колбеки уже там, где убивается активити? Я подозреваю что это делается как то по другому, но как именно - не понимаю.

Comment: [не особо разбираюсь в синтаксисе] объявите переменную вне метода жизненного цикла, а в `onCreate` присвоите ей значение. Кроме того, можно не сохранять её, а использовать [`removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо комментариям @ВасяВоронцов. Я решил вопрос простым путем - убиваю все процессы в handler'ах при выходе из activity. Для примера, если делать выход через кнопку "назад":

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    screenHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) // отключаем looper
    finish() // принудительно закрываем активность
}
```